# r shiny storing plot and data frame in list

Tags: r, list, shiny

I'm trying to output a graph and a data frame by storing the output of my function in a list and then calling the list values but my graph isn't showing up and theres no error message. Ive created a dummy example to showcase my issue.

Here is my code

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("title"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier"),
            actionButton("Go", "Go", style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; margin: auto")
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            fluidRow(
                align = "center",
                plotOutput("GraphEF")),
                tableOutput("EFWeightsTable")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    OPw <- reactiveValues()
    observeEvent(input$Go, {
        
        if(input$EF){
            showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL)) 
            OPw$LIST1 <- X(5,10,20)
        }
        removeModal() 
    })
    
    output$GraphEF <- renderPlot({ 
        OPw$LIST1[[1]]
    },height = 550, width = 700)
    
    output$EFWeightsTable <- renderTable({ 
        OPw$LIST1[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
    )
    
    #Function
    X <- function(a,b,c){
        PLOT1 <- plot(c(1,2),c(3,4), type="l")
        DF1 <- data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,4))
        
        return(list(c(PLOT1,DF1)))
    }
        
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Your help is very appreciated, thank you

Comment: There is no return value for the `plot`.  `return(list(PLOT1,DF1))`. You don't need the `c` in between, you get `NULL` for the `plot`

Comment: I meant to say that if you create an object `out <- plot(1, 1); out
NULL`, there is no return value for plot, thus it will be NULL.  My previous comment is about creating a list in the correct way i.e. `list(PLOT1, DF1)` instead of `c(PLOT1, DF1)` - (this results in changing the structure of 'DF1' to a list of columns instead of data.frame

Comment: instead of the base R plot, you could use `ggplot` and store it as an object

Comment: ahh I see. Yeah makes sense I will try using ggplot instead. I thought regular plots could also be stored. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few mistakes in your code - Here is the solution with Base R Plot.
The code include detail comments where needed explaining what is happening.

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  OPw <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$Go, {
    
    if(input$EF){
      showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL)) 
      OPw$LIST1 <- X(5,10,20)
    }
    removeModal() 
  })
  
  output$GraphEF <- renderPlot({ 
    OPw$LIST1[[1]]
  },height = 550, width = 700)
  
  output$EFWeightsTable <- renderTable(
    {
      # Here it seem OP use the wrong reference [[1]] where it should be [[2]]
      OPw$LIST1[[2]]
    }, colnames = TRUE
  )
  
  #Function
  X <- function(a,b,c){
    # Base R plot doesn't return a value but will always output to panel plot
    plot(c(1,2),c(3,4), type="l")
    # To save it to object for later use recordPlot() function after plot function
    PLOT1 <- recordPlot()
    DF1 <- data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,4))
    # Here only use list(...) instead of list(c(...))
    # c(...) convert all objects passed to it into vector - you don't want that.
    return(list(PLOT1,DF1))
  }
  
}
```

#### Here is the output

[image]